# ClickOnce and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have a WPF Application Developed in Visual Studio 2015 Professional but I am wanting to deploy this as an install-able application, VS2015 seems to be enforcing ClickOnce.

Reading through the Stack Overflow questions in the past, I have tried removing the 'Sign the ClickOnce Manifests' and 'Enable ClickOnce Security Settings'. However as soon as I compile the application again the 'Enable ClickOnce Security Settings' automatically enables itself again.

Going to the MSDN site the Windows Installer Help stops at Visual Studio 2012 when the same reference page has ClickOnce Help through to Visual Studio 2015.

This needs to run in an environment restricted by AppLocker and I am searching all through Visual Studio and Googling to get this to install to Program Files (x86) and NOT ClickOnce.

NOTE: Under Visual Studio 2013 this was an install-able application that deployed to Program Files (x86). After opening the solution in VS2015 and updating I can only deploy as ClickOnce.

If anyone has experienced this in Visual Studio 2015 and can point me in the appropriate direction this will be great.

Many thanks,

Comment: If you just want an installer look at WiX or NSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your time, I have found a Microsoft Installer to add the VS2010 Installer Projects Package to VS2015 and I am away laughing.
This is available here, https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Many thanks,